# Drupal 8 .theme file changes slow to update

Tags: drupal-8

Whenever I make any change to my .theme file, it can take up to several minutes for the changes to show on page refresh. I've followed all the steps for disabling the cache from here https://www.drupal.org/node/2598914 but it still seems to be caching for any .theme and .module files and when I add a new hook or change a .yml file, it won't be recognized until I use the clear cache button at admin/config/development/performance AND wait several minutes for the site to update.

Any changes made to other files are showing up immediately as they should. That includes any Twig, CSS, and JS files, any controllers, blocks, or other module files.

I've also tried changing themes, disabling view block caching, editing all #cache variables max-age to 0 in the block preprocess hook, setting my sql max-allowed-packets to 16M, and going to core/rebuild.php several times but nothing has worked.

Comment: I used this guide: https://www.drupaleasy.com/quicktips/enabling-development-mode-local-drupal-8-site if you have drupal console, just run `drupal site:mode dev` and it will disable all the caching

Answer (score 0):

If you have drush try `drush cr` which is the same as `drush cache-rebuild`

If not try to go to Administration > Configuration > Development > Performance and clear the cache from there.

for reference: [Drupal Docs](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/administering-drupal-7-site/clearing-or-rebuilding-drupals-cache)